# Why am I getting this ValidationException in my save method?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a CourseOffering domain class which has a property of type Term, which is another domain class.

CourseOffering

```
class CourseOffering {

    static fetchMode = [term: 'eager']

    String title
    String key 
    Term term
}
```

Term

```
class Term {
    String description
    String identifier
    String isCurrent
    Date midterm
}
```

I have a page to create a new CourseOffering, here is the gsp for that page. Edit: forgot to mention that the variable 'terms' that I am using here is simply a passed in value of Term.list()

```
<g:form name="myForm">
    <div class="input">
        Course Title <input type="text" name="title">
        <br><br>
        Course Key  <input type="text" name="key"> 
        <br><br>
        Term <select name="term">
                <g:each var="term" in="${terms}">
                    <option value="${term.id}" <g:if test="${term.isCurrent ==  'Y'}">selected</g:if>>${term.description}</option>
                </g:each>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <g:actionSubmit action="save" value="Create" />
    </div>
</g:form>
```

Here is the save method in the CourseOfferingController

```
def save() {
    CourseOffering newCourse = new CourseOffering(params)
    Term term = Term.get(params.term)
    newCourse.term = term
    assert(newCourse.term instanceof Term) // I put this here to make sure it was a Term!

    if (newCourse.save(failOnError: true)) {
        flash.message = [type: 'status', text: "Succesfully added ${newCourse.title} to the list of course offerings."]
    }
    else {
        flash.message = [type: 'errors', text:"Unable to add course to the list of course offerings."]
    }

    redirect(action: 'index')
}
```

Aaaannnddddd this is what happens when I try to save the newly created CourseOffering

> URI: /office/courseOffering/index
>   Class: grails.validation.ValidationException
>   Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save(): - Field error in object 'mcidc.CourseOffering' on field 'term': rejected value [mcidc.Term : 9618]; codes [typeMismatch.mcidc.CourseOffering.term,typeMismatch.term,typeMismatch.mcidc.Term,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [mcidc.CourseOffering.term,term]; arguments []; default message [term]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'mcidc.Term' for property 'term'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [mcidc.Term] for property 'term': no matching editors or conversion strategy found**
>
> Around line 73 of grails-app\controllers\mcidc\CourseOfferingController.groovy
>   70:     newCourse.term = term
>   71:     assert(newCourse.term instanceof Term)
>   72:
>   73:     if (newCourse.save(failOnError: true)) {
>   74:         flash.message = [type: 'status', text: "Succesfully added ${newCourse.title} to the list of course offerings."]
>   75:     }
>   76:     else {

What's going on here? I proved that newCourse.term is of type Term with my assert statement, so why is it saying that it's a String? I'm so confused.

Sorry for the horrible formatting of that stacktrace but I really battled with the formatting on here and I couldn't figure out how to make it look nice. I tried to just post a picture of it, but I don't have 10 reputation. The exception is happening on newCourse.save(failOnError: true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
CourseOffering newCourse = new CourseOffering(params)
```

Because you created the newCourse by passing in the params, you are binding the param 'term' which has no means to convert convert one from a string.

Renaming the `term` param to `termId` and this will move you forward.

GSP View:

```
Term <select name="termId">
                <g:each var="term" in="${terms}">
                    <option value="${term.id}" <g:if test="${term.isCurrent ==  'Y'}">selected</g:if>>${term.description}</option>
                </g:each>
        </select>
```

Controller:

```
def save() {
    CourseOffering newCourse = new CourseOffering(params)
    Term term = Term.get(params.termId)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution. I understand now that it was trying to map params.term to the term property of newCourse and I understand why that wouldn't work. However I am still confused as to why that takes priority over me declaring newCourse.term = term afterwards. It seems like it should have failed before I attempted to save it, so why is it failing because of a mapping issue after I already declared what the term should be?

Comment: The databinding done when you pass `params` to the constructor populates the instance's `errors`. You may just need to `clearErrors()` before your `save()` call.

Comment: Awesome! I did not know that. So because although nothing was currently wrong with the instance, the errors that got created upon the initial binding were still present, which is why it was failing. Mystery solved.